# Axis: log SOAP http request and response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, client, axis

I'm working with Axis to build an SOAP client. I'd like to print somewhere complete http request and response. I managed to create handler, which prints SOAP envelopes. How can I extend it to print complete http?

```
public class CustomMessageHandler extends GenericHandler {

    HandlerInfo hi;

    public void init(HandlerInfo info) {
        hi = info;
        System.out.println("CustomMessageHandler initialized");
    }

    public QName[] getHeaders() {
        return hi.getHeaders();
    }

    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext context) {
        try {
            SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
            SOAPMessage msg = smc.getMessage();
            System.out.println("request:");
            msg.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println("");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext context) {
        try {
            SOAPMessageContext smc = (SOAPMessageContext) context;
            SOAPMessage msg = smc.getMessage();
            System.out.println("response:");
            msg.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println("");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This link has the completed implementation->https://developervisits.wordpress.com/2017/06/20/apache-axis-logging-of-soap-requestresponse-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

The Request and Response handler at this stage probably will not have a complete Request and response. Probably the Axis Servlet will do it or a HTTP Handler.
Have tried writing a filter and log the complete request and response ?